# Sitecore Solr index FieldNameTranslator is null

Tags: solr, indexing

I am currently playing around with Sitecore indexes - both Solr and Lucene.

I have made my own custom index and it works fine for Lucene, but I cannot get it to work with Solr.

My problem is that the `FieldNameTranslator` is null for my index, whenever I use the Solr configuration.

I am using the Sitecore ContentSearch dlls to get the indexes in the following manner:

```
 this.IndexName = indexName;
 this.index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);           
 var i = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
```

As a test, I also tried fetching the `sitecore_master_index` and that seems to work. I get the following:

[image]

I get an index, but whenever I query it by calling `GetQueryable<T>`, then it fails with the following error:

> Exception: System.ArgumentNullException Message: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator Source:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrIndexParameters..ctor(IIndexValueFormatter
>   valueFormatter, IFieldQueryTranslatorMap`1 fieldQueryTranslators,
>   FieldNameTranslator fieldNameTranslator, IExecutionContext[]
>   executionContexts, IFieldMapReaders fieldMap, Boolean
>   convertQueryDatesToUtc)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1..ctor(SolrSearchContext
>   context, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchContext.GetQueryable[TItem](IExecutionContext[]
>   executionContexts)

I am using SolrNet as IOC which, from what I can read in the documentation, should work from 8.2 and upwards. If I use one of the other IOCs then it works just fine.

So my question is, what could go wrong here? And can somebody explain me what the `FieldNameTranslator` is and how it is initiated in configuration? (where I suppose it is set)

Comment: Can you share the config of your custom index?

Comment: The main possible issue here is that your solr cores are corrupted. Try to delete the cores and re create them and see if it works

Comment: Hard to say without the config, but have you populated the solr managed schema for your custom index?